# How to format texts so they look just like shown in the website?

Tags: python, selenium

I am web scraping a website with Python selenium. This is the code on the website:

[image]

and I'd like texts to look like shown on the website, i.e. easy to 'read' with line breaks, in an organized format.

I tried using

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('record-content.record-information.record-content_j').text
```

but there are \n \n characters inside. I tried `print(text)`, and looks better. But is there a way to store the text in a dataframe or something so it is saved in an organized format.
The website looks like this: [image]
When I tried

```
rawData=driver.find_element_by_class_name('record-content.record-information.record-content_j').text
sanitizedData = rawData.replace('\n','')
print(BeautifulSoup(sanitizedData, 'html.parser').prettify())
```

The output looks like this:

[image]
The 'br' tags for line breaks just disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

As we've extracted via `.text` content with no `<br>` tags included, we can use BeautifulSoup to actually prittify our output. Similarly, we could use `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` if you'd like to maintain html, and strip any new line characters if needed. Hope this helps :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    """ Start Firefox instance """
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://yoursite.com")

    """ Extract content """
    rawData = driver.find_element_by_class_name('record-content.record-information.record-content_j').text

    """ Print to console """
    print(BeautifulSoup(rawData, 'html.parser').prettify())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method but seems it is not what I am looking for. I've updated my question. I guess driver.find_element_by_class_name(XXX).text will simply remove those <br> tags?

Comment: @hjgh I've update the original answer, I think it could now be what you're looking for :)